# Selenium on .NET 6.0 is slower than .NET Framework 4.8.1

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, .net-4.8

### The issue

I have recently migrated my Selenium automation project from **.Net Framework 4.8.1** to **.Net 6.0** and noticed a significant change in the execution time of tests. They became slower. For one TestFixture the duration increased from 26 mins to 56 mins.

### Investigation

I was searching for the issue on the Internet, and found this article: [GitHub - HttpWebRequest hits 1s timeout when resolving http://localhost on Win10 (.NET Framework is fast)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23581) which some users are facing while running Selenium against http://localhost/.
I'm not using localhost. The entire testing framework is bound to a URL of a staging environment hosted on Azure.

The conditions are identical: the code, all NuGet packages are updated, staging environment is the same, etc. Profiling the project shows that WebDriver requests are **2-5 times slower on average**.

Durations of some tests from the .Net Framework project:

[image: .Net Framework results]

**.Net 6.0 is almost twice as slow:**

[image: .Net 6.0]

### .NET Profiling

I'm using a wrapper class for WebElement that handles Exceptions and Explicit waits, below is an example of a Click() method. If you look at comments with the execution times, you'll notice how **.Net 6.0 is especially slower with WebDriverWait**:

```
public bool Click(Driver driver)                                                     
{                                                                                    
    InitWait(driver);  //.NET - 415ms, Framework - 28ms
     _log.Debug($"Trying to click {_locator}");                                              
     try                                                                                   
     {                                                                                       
         el = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(_locator));  //.NET - 266ms, Framework - 20ms       
         el.Click();  //.NET - 49ms, Framework - 39ms
         return true;                                                                 
     }                                                                                       
     catch (Exception e)                                                                     
     {                                                                                       
         if (e is ElementClickInterceptedException)                                          
         {                                                                                  
             ScrollToElementJS(driver);                                                     
             el.Click();                                                                    
             return true;                                                                   
         }                                                                                   
         else                                                                              
         {                                                                                   
             Fail($"Can't click element '{_locator}'", e);                                   
             throw;                                                                          
         }
      }
}
```

```
private protected void InitWait(Driver driver, int seconds = 30)
{
    if (wait == null)
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.webDriverInstance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
    else
        wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
    WaitUntilLoadingCompletes(driver);  //.NET - 307ms, Framework - 90ms
}
```

```
public void WaitUntilLoadingCompletes(Driver driver)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver.webDriverInstance, _thirty);
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));

    Element spinner = new Element(By.XPath(Config.spinnerXPath));
    Element spinnerBar = new Element(By.XPath("//div[@id='loading-bar']"));
    Element divOverlay = new Element(By.XPath("//div[@class='overlay']"));

    try
    {
         wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(spinner._locator)); //.NET - 124ms, Framework - 20ms
         wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(spinnerBar._locator)); //.NET - 97ms, Framework - 10ms
         wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(divOverlay._locator)); //.NET - 102ms, Framework - 55ms
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Fail($"One of the loaders at '{_locator}' is visible after {wait.Timeout.ToPrettyFormat()}", e);
    }
}
```

### Dependencies

```
<PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" Version="3.16.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="WebDriverManager" Version="2.17.0" />
```

Comment: This difference is negligible. Have you tried on bigger tests?

Comment: I would be concerned that your test fixture took 26 minutes normally! What is the test doing?

Comment: The entire Test Fixture contains of 24 tests. Unfortunately, there is no way to parallelize them - have to run sequentially. As I mentioned in the first paragraph - the duration on net framework is twice as faster. 56 vs 26 minutes

Comment: The difference per test is negligible, but scale matters a lot here. If you only run 2 tests, just move on with life. Not worth your time. If you have 2,000 tests to run then we are talking quite a bit of time.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the application under test that is running slower?

Comment: I have multiple test fixtures, overall there are around 1000 tests. All of them are as twice as slower. I left the entire solution to run overnight and it took ~3 hours to complete on net framework while it's been 7 hours already and the core part is still executing. The application under test is the same performance-wise. I specifically scaled it up to a maximum just to confirm my observation.

Comment: Have you tried updating Selenium whichever web driver you are using?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to .NET 7? .NET 6 will be dropping out of support soon.

Comment: Selenium will use localhost to send/receive requests to the browser... so that issue you linked to may still be the culprit.  (btw, .net7 drops out of support before .net6... .net6 is the LTS version)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have upgraded the project to .Net 7 but, unfortunately, it didn't help much.

Comment: btw, ignoring StaleElement Exceptions is probably not a good idea.  One your reference goes stale you'd need to find the element reference again.  (and WebDriverWait already ignores nosuchelement exceptions, so that bit shouldn't be needed either)

Comment: @pcalkins yeah, that is the only explanation which makes sense to me. I tried to disable IPv6 on loopback addresses according to this solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/218745/disable-ipv6-on-loopback-address-localhost-computer-name but it didn't help with the issue. Not sure if that would've helped at all.

Comment: @pcalkins I agree, thanks! The entire testing framework is pretty old, so I remember someone might've put it there for a reason, and everyone in the team is scared of changing the wrapper implementation since all the tests are working correctly 98% of the times :) As for the NoSuchElementException, this was added to in order to avoid breaks there while debugging

Comment: you might try adding a hosts entry... something like 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254766/discussion-between-pwrngr-and-pcalkins).